# What files can be removed when using dropbox on an external hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, dropbox

I read on https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/89 :

> If the external drive is disconnected from the computer while Dropbox is running, **there's a small chance that the application will start deleting files** before realizing that the entire drive has been removed. Again: When it comes to using an external drive for your Dropbox folder, tread carefully.

What files are they talking about? Files on my dropbox account that correspond to the content of my external hard drive?

I use dropbox on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files synced will be monitored using  automatic directory monitoring in windows where the file modification or removal will be updated to dropbox instance where it will sync the status to the server. If these files are not available then it will be taken as deleted.

In your case normally the status of the files availability will be checked based on the path of the file. For example the drive is connected with the drive letter  "E:" and disconnected from the machine. During this disconnect period if any other driver connected with the same drive letter "E" then there might me be a possibility for the files to get update ed in drop box server as deleted.

In case if no drives available with drive letter "E". Then delete operation wont occurs.

Note : This issue can be avoided by dropbox by taking the disk UUID for file availability validation rather than taking it's drive letter assigned.

Hope this clear

Comment: You should especially be careful if the newly lettered E drive (not the Dropbox drive) has a folder called Dropbox. When Dropbox starts up, no detection of a e:\Dropbox folder is a good thing, but if it sees a e:\Dropbox but it is empty... this can cause the delete process. Worst case, you have to undelete the deleted files. You get a 30 day grace period for Pro users and I think unlimited grace period for business users.

Answer (score 1):

"Files on my dropbox account that correspond to the content of my external hard drive?"

Exactly.

If you have a sync setup between the DropBox servers and an external drive, and you pull the external drive, it may think the files have been purposefully removed, and will sync as such -- deleting the copies from the Dropbox servers.