# Synology and Dropbox

Tags: macos, sync, nas, dropbox, synology

I'm planning to buy a Synology NAS to use as an always-on media server. I currently have all my photos and music in my Dropbox folder on two Macs, and would like to simply mirror them onto the NAS as well. I asked Dropbox support about this:

> I realize you probably don't know the Synology software. But that's the box I'm looking at, and they have a feature called "Cloud Station", which says "As soon as you save a change, it automatically updates the copies on the other devices."     So my use case looks something like this: mount a Synology folder on my iMac and my MacBook, and use this service to keep the two in sync via the Synology drive. Now, each time a file changes, it will change locally, so that Dropbox will wake up and sync the file. But Synology will also be syncing the same file. Will confusion ensue, or will things be kept straight?

and they replied

> It sounds like that solution may work well -- I believe other users have had success with this set up. Please be aware that if you encounter any issues with the NAS in the future and write in to support, you will be told that NAS is unsupported and, unless your Dropbox is on a supported configuration, we are unable to help. There are just too many variables to account for.
>   I'd like to know how things work out for you. Feel free to follow up and let me know!

Does anyone have any experience with this solution, and does it work?

Another strategy that I'm considering is simply treating the NAS as a third Dropbox client and letting Dropbox do all the work of keeping things in sync. Will that work? (It seems to me that that requires running the Dropbox client app on the NAS, which I don't know if it's possible or not).

So those are two approaches, but I'd be interested in hearing how anyone else has approached this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Synology NAS (DS413) and they have a "package" made by Synology called "Cloud Sync" and it allows you to sync files to/from Dropbox (and Google Drive, Baidu Cloud, OneDrive, Box, and Hubic for now).

CloudSync can acts like a 3rd DropBox client and simply sync back and forth as per normal.

This may be of interest (from their help file):

> **Default action for conflicted copy:** 
>  If a file or directory is modified
>   on both your local DiskStation and remote public cloud account at the
>   same time, Cloud Sync will try to keep the local changes as much as
>   possible, and the remote changes will be saved as one revision if the
>   cloud service supports versioning.

About the 2 solutions you proposed:

1. Letting Synology do the sync vs
2. Letting Dropbox do the sync

It may be best to let DropBox do the sync (so you still work on local files that are located on your own devices, unless you run out of space). Reason being (also taken from their help file):

> **No incremental update:**
>  Some cloud service providers do not releases a public API for developers to track file changes. This means Cloud Sync must re-download and sync the entire file every time a file has been modified, even when you've only made partial modifications. On the other hand, cloud service providers' official PC applications might be able to re-download and sync the modified bits only, reducing sync time.
>   **No local network sync:** 
>  Certain public cloud service providers offer LAN sync, a technique that allows one client to obtain files from existing clients in the same local area network (LAN), thus significantly boosting sync speed. However, LAN sync accesses files in client computers without notifying them, which could possibly become a security backdoor. Therefore, this feature is not included in Cloud Sync.

DropBox do have Incremental update, and also allows local network sync so files between your Mac should update faster (as opposed to the Synology box which will only get update from DropBox).

My suggestion:

- If you are not running out of space on your devices, keep DropBox client, and let both Mac and NAS to become DropBox client. It does means you have 4 copies of files (3 on your device, and 1 on dropbox cloud), but it is safer, and you will work faster that way (work with local files).
- If you are running out of space on your devices, then letting both Mac to map network drive on the NAS means you only have 2 copies of the files (1 on nas, 1 on cloud) and only your NAS does the sync work. Note1: Editing files on network drive (even if it is local) will be slower than if the files are locally available on your HDD. Note2: As mentioned above, with this solution you don't have incremental update, so if you are dealing with big files, your bandwidth might get used up quite a lot.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. The files I would want on the NAS won't change very often, so the lack of LAN sync shouldn't be an issue. As I recall, the cloud client on Synology supports selective sync with Dropbox. Two questions: 1) Do you use this setup, or any setup with Dropbox, yourself? 2) It sounds like everything you described works by using the embedded Synology Dropbox client rather than the one supplied by Dropbox. Is that correct?

Comment: #1 I do use Synology original CloudSync client (which allows dropbox sync from it). I mainly use CloudSync to get an additional copy of DropBox for Just in case, but I still use Dropbox client on all my PCs. #2 I'm not aware that Dropbox made their own client for installation on Synology NAS.

Answer (score 1):

In dropbox the requested feature will work as you expected the main concern is that If the external drive is disconnected from the computer while Dropbox is running, there's a small chance that the application will start deleting files before realizing that the entire drive has been removed. Again: When it comes to using an external drive for your Dropbox folder, tread carefully.

Comment: So I can run the Dropbox client app on the Synology box? Also, is the concern you raise any different for the NAS than it is for a client like my laptop?

Comment: Yes you can run, but the data should be available for the dropbox to access every time. Also refer the superuser link where i explained how data monitoring done in dropbox for better understand of your case

http://superuser.com/questions/845023/what-files-can-be-removed-when-using-dropbox-on-an-external-hard-drive/845038#845038

Comment: As I understand your answer in the link above, this situation regarding deleting files can happen only if some other device connects using the same drive letter as the disconnected drive during some short time window. As I'm using a Mac, there are no drive letters, but rather Unix mount points. So is that risk completely averted in this case, or do I misunderstand what you said?